# RoR NoMethodError in Credits#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Hi, 
I am doing my homework around the building a simple RoR app and got stuck with the following:
I created a Scaffold called "Credit", and a relationship between the User and Credit model:
Here are my files**

credit.rb

```
class Credit < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :amount, :user_id
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :merchant

end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

# Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me,
                :first_name, :last_name, :profile_name 

# attr_accessible :title, :body
has_many :statuses
has_many :merchants
has_many :credits

def  full_name
first_name + " " + last_name
end
end
```

**When trying to create a new credit entry with the following form:**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@credit) do |f| %>
<%= f.error_notification %>

<div class="form-inputs">
 <%= f.input :amount %>
 <%= f.input :user_id, collection: User.all %>

</div>


<div class="form-actions">
 <%= f.button :submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

**I get the following error,**

NoMethodError in Credits#new

Showing/Users/andreucasadella/rails_projects/monedero/app/view credits/_form.html.erb where line #6 raised:

undefined method `user_id' for #

**Any idea?**

Comment: Does you credit model has `user_id` column?

Comment: I suggest opening up the Rails console, creating a Credit object, and taking a look inside.  Pry and Pry-debugger are nice for this sort of thing since Pry allows you to 'cd' into an object and have a look at all of its properties.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/280-pry-with-rails

Comment: Yes,

    class Credit < ActiveRecord::Base
     attr_accessible :amount, :user_id
     belongs_to :user
     belongs_to :merchant

    end

Comment: @user1953246 - This does not mean it has a column in a database. Check it inside your schema file.

Comment: Ahh! You were right. I was missing a db migration file. Now it works. Thanks! Post your answer so I can mark it as solved buddy

class AddUserIdtoCredit < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
   add_column :credits, :user_id, :integer
  end
end